# Update data using cloud function and angular

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am new in firebase environment.
I want to update data in the firebase using cloud function using angular service.
I am able to fetch data in angular from firebase using cloud function as follows

```
readUsers(): Observable<Person[]>{
return this._http
.get(“https://us-central1-partner-f3f0b.cloudfunctions.net/getCustomer")
.map(res => res.json());
}
```

And cloud fuction is as follows

```
exports.getCustomer = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
res.header(‘Content-Type’, ‘application/json’);
res.header(‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’, ‘*’);
res.header(‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’, ‘Content-Type’);
//respond to CORS preflight requests
if (req.method === ‘OPTIONS’) {
res.status(204).send(‘’);
}
// Get a database reference to our posts
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref(“customer”);
// Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
ref.on(“value”, function (snapshot) {
console.log(snapshot.val());
res.status(200).json({ customer: snapshot.val() });
}, function (errorObject) {
console.log(“The read failed: “ + errorObject.code);
});
});
```

The below cloud function is working and updating the firebase database .

```
exports.getOneProducts = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
res.header(‘Content-Type’, ‘application/json’);
res.header(‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’, ‘*’);
res.header(‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’, ‘Content-Type’);
//respond to CORS preflight requests
if (req.method === ‘OPTIONS’) {
res.status(204).send(‘’);
}
// Get a database reference to our posts
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref(“/messages/-L82AfhFTr4odsh1GMId”);
ref.update({ original: “New trainer” });
});
```

I am facing the challenge here how to pass data in json format in angular 4 and update in firebase database using google cloud function .
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put your JSON in the body content of your Request (which shall be a POST) and get it in the cloud function through `req.body.xxxxx`

E.g. if your request body content is the following JSON {original: “New trainer”} you will get the "New trainer" value in your fucntion by doing `req.body.original`

Comment: Extra Question: Why are you not using the web library to interact with Firebase from your web client? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

Comment: Thanks for the answer .Can you please specify how to pass the request in body in angular.Can you please give a sample code?

Comment: @BikramSao I am afraid not... I am not specialised in Angular. Personally I use Vue.js and in this specific case I use Axios (https://github.com/axios/axios). You will find in the example section how to  send a POST Request with Axios. I've rapidly searched on the net for "POST request with angular" and found this https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request: you would just declare data as an object I guess.